# Запутался в JS скрипте, как лучше сделать?

Tags: javascript

Сам скрипт https://jsfiddle.net/oyhvy9wf/

```
var chairs = document.getElementById("tab");

var n = 0;
var active = chairs.onmouseover = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = 'Наведено на ' + e.target.id; var n = 1; var nid = e.target.id;

  if(n > 0){
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = 'Наведено на '+nid;
  }
};
```

Идея была в том, что при наведении на раз, два, три - каждая надпись меняла цвет на красный и обратно на дефолтный, когда ни на одну из них курсор не наведён. Но возникли сложности:

1. Непонятно, что лучше использовать в данном случае - функцию, функциональное выражение или объект с замыканием каким ни будь
2. id="tab", с одной стороны, помогает находить объекты внутри группы, с другой, стороны так же забивает вывод собой, что не гуд, хотелось бы отслеживать не его самого, а только дочерние объекты
3. Без mouseout все свойства остаются после удаления мышки, но поставить его корректно никак не получается

Как в этом случае лучше выстроить архитектуру скрипта?

Answer (score -4):

Думаю, что с помощью jQuery это делается гораздо проще

```js
$("#tab>div").hover(function(){
    innerText = $(this).html();
    $("#out").text(innerText);
    $(this).addClass("red");
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="tab">
  <div>раз</div>
  <div>два</div>
  <div>три</div>
</div>
<br><div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: о jQuery и речи не было в вопросе.

Comment: Может человек забыл про jq, и ему не принципиален метод, а главное реализовать идею, которую описал в вопросе.

Comment: Я не забыл про JQ а намеренно им не пользуюсь ))